# Ranorex v5.0 doesn’t click button sporadical

Tags: ranorex

I have a ranorex project, which automated an use case with clicking 5 buttons in an application.
To set up this project I used the record function. I defined some sleep times between the clicks. 
The run with the clicks is in a loop, where the loop count is dynamically defined. One button of the five and always the same button, Ranorex "ignores" sometimes. According to the log file, the button is visible and enabled and ranorex also runs the code with the Click(), but the application doesn’t receive the click. Before in code the click is called, I check with an “If” whether the button is visible and enabled - and if the click() is called (or doesn't), I log it to ranorexlog. Sometimes the application is running through and all the clicks work and sometimes this button click is missing one or more times. It doesn’t depend on the sleep time between the clicks, because I tried long and small pause times. It doesn’t depend on the focus of the application, too, because I switched the focus several times.

Does anybody know this problem, workarounds or what I’m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the obvious workaround is to use Mouse.Click("{Button}") with a 0 duration rather than invoking the click event, or if you are invoking the mouse click invoke the buttons click action. (sorry since they are both named Click() i don't know which one you are using).

As to what is happening, from your description it sounds like your script is finding more than one element with the same xpath.  This would cause issues with the click event because it may try to click on the element, but it's the first xpath that matches not the second.  Are there any optional elements in this sequence of button clicks that appear? for instance a busy spinner with inner text of "OK" that is hidden from view when you are clicking a button on a form with inner text of "OK" would cause two elements to be found if the xpath was looking for an inner text of ok.  This element that is causing may not have been caught in the recorder because it might not have been present at the time.

Another possibility if you are using Mouse.Click() (particularly if this is a website)is that it is possible your button is not actually on the screen, I know that should be taken care of by the visible check but it is visible on the dom even though it is not visible on the screen that causes issues.

I highly recommend do not use the recorder to create test suites that need to be re-runnable.  It would actually be better to use the spy tool to create a repository or several repositories for the product you are testing, this way you can be sure the xpaths are all unique, which using the recorder there is no gaurantee.  You can actually record with the created repository, and ranorex will attempt to find item in the repository before creating a new item, so the recorder will use this repository when creating recordings.